Type of iterator is Any in zip
The following script:
from collections.abc import Iterable, Iterator


class A(Iterable):
    _list: list[int]

    def __init__(self, *args: int) -> None:
        self._list = list(args)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[int]:
        return iter(self._list)


a = A(1, 2, 3)

for i in a:
    reveal_type(i)

for s, j in zip("abc", a):
    reveal_type(j)


yields the following mypy output:
$ mypy test.py
test.py:17: note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
test.py:20: note: Revealed type is "Any"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file

Why is the type Any when iterating on zip, but not on the object directly?
Note, subclassing class A(Iterable[int]) does allow for correct type resolution, but that's not the question here ;)

I'll write a better answer tonight, but here's the summary: for i in a is checked by type checker on type level by looking at __iter__ member's return type. Iterable inheritance does not matter there, no protocol comparison happens. On the other hand, zip is a plain old function, declared as taking arguments of Iterable[_T1], Iterable[_T2], etc. up to 6 (AFAIC) overloads. In this case A is interpreted as Iterable, and since you declared it Iterable[Any], __iter__ is not taken into account at all. __iter__ was only checked for interface conformance - in A body.

Note that you'll get desired int if you omit Iterable inheritance altogether. That's because Iterable is a Protocol for mypy, so anything not inheriting from it will be checked for conformance and inferred to the best possible level (structural subtyping). Something that has __iter__(self) -> int is a subtype of Iterable[int], so can be inferred as such. But filling type vars in base classes for you would violate PEP484 and thus doesn't happen. If you inherit from Iterable[Any], you probably have a reason to do so, and mypy must respect it.

Comparing for loop and zip object is not an apples-to-apples comparison.
For loop
How is for i in X checked? At least in current mypy source, for loop is checked by looking up __iter__ signature on the type of X and using its return type. So it doesn't look at your Iterable inheritance, it finds the nearest __iter__ in MRO which happens to be the one you provided.
Why is it implemented this way? For loop is a language native construct, defined at the syntactical level - in some sense it's more fundamental than existence of some protocol types encapsulating iteration behaviour.
zip
Now, zip is just a class. It defines its own __iter__ method, so for a,b in zip(A, B) will be checked according to its return type. This class is generic in iterator type, supporting up to 5 distinct iterables and falling back to general case for 6 and more. Here's what it looks like: typeshed permalink. There is no black magic involved.
I'll quote the relevant part:
class zip(Iterator[_T_co]):
    ...
    @overload
    def __new__(cls, iter1: Iterable[_T1], /, *, strict: bool = ...) -> zip[tuple[_T1]]: ...
    @overload
    def __new__(cls, iter1: Iterable[_T1], iter2: Iterable[_T2], /, *, strict: bool = ...) -> zip[tuple[_T1, _T2]]: ...
    ....

    def __iter__(self) -> Self: ...
    def __next__(self) -> _T_co: ...

(there are version-dependent branches and more overloads, I'll omit them here for brewity)
You hit the two-arg overload. It looks for _T1 and _T2 by "solving" the following equation:
Iterable[_T2] = A

Here's the culprit: you declare that A is an Iterable[Any]. Omitting generic type vars is fully equivalent to providing Any instead. There is no room for type checker inference. So mypy happily says "wow, I already know that A <: Iterable[Any], hence _T2 = Any, next". It does not touch the MRO and does not look into Iterable semantics at all: it just wants to know what type var should parameterize it.
At this point, mypy already knows that A is a subtype of Iterable[Any] - you told it so! Even if your class doesn't contain __iter__ at all, mypy would have already reported that at definition, no need to repeat here. It would be wasteful to recheck protocol conformance at every usage site, and would also produce a bunch of undesired errors. Imagine that, for some strange reason, you have the class as follows:
class B(Iterable[str]):
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[int]: ...  # type: ignore[override]

Oops. This makes no sense here, but may happen in real life for more complex protocols. If mypy were to check __iter__ everywhere, you'd have to # type: ignore all places where B is used as Iterable[str].
Structural subtyping
Side note: Iterable quacks like a typing.Protocol. If you do not inherit from it at all, your class still can be a subtype of Iterable - that's called structural subtyping. It will even pass assert issubclass(A, Iterable)! If you don't declare implementation explicitly, type checkers should infer the corresponding type as precisely as possible. So your case written without explicit Iterable inheritance would produce the desired outcome.
General note
I do understand your problem with this. Actually I'm also not sure that this approach is fully justified: probably for loop should also treat the iterable as Iterable, solving the same equation? But that's how the implementation currently behaves, and both approaches are equally valid IMO.

I'm not positive, but I think A is not sufficiently generic (Iterable is equivalent to Iterable[Any]). If you add a type variable to the definition of A, you'll get the expected revealed type.
T = TypeVar('T')

class A(Iterable[T]):
    _list: list[T]

    def __init__(self, *args: T) -> None:
        self._list = list(args)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T]:
        return iter(self._list)

As far as I can tell, knowing the return type of A.__iter__ is not sufficient for zip to bind int to its own internal type variable. I don't know if that's an oversight that can be fixed or not. (I'll note that PyRight also reports the type of j as Unknown, which is a type it uses to distinguish between different uses of Any.)

PyRight's case is simpler, as it doesn't type zip strongly: Type of "zip" is "type[zip[Unknown]]".
mypy (via typeshed) reports a more complete type, though it's complicated by the fact that it's an overload to handle the varying number of iterables that zip can accept. The relevant case here is
def [_T_co, _T1, _T2] (typing.Iterable[_T1`-1], typing.Iterable[_T2`-2], *, strict: builtins.bool =) 
   -> builtins.zip[tuple[_T1`-1, _T2`-2]]`

When you make A fully generic, mypy is able to "extract" int from the type of a in order to bind int to _T2`-2.

Pyright's zip[Unknown] is apparently just a UI bug or something - Pyright displays type[...] for classes, while mypy always expands that to constructor signature. Try adding reveal_type(s) - it knows it's str correctly. It uses (almost) the same typeshed, after all, AFAIC, and the treatment looks very similar to mypy.

(and mypy definitely doesn't bind A to _T2, please fix that, we don't see A as Iterable[A] unless A is str...)

Ah, I wasn't sure if PyRight used its own type specifications for built-ins. (Also, I wasn't sure if PyRight made some distinction between zip itself and a "saturated" instance of zip, but in hindsight that would seem like a silly thing to do.)

No special-casing, just typeshed magic (5 args work, 6 resolve to Any): https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&reportUnnecessaryTypeIgnoreComment=true&code=GYewTgBAhgjANFATAgzAgLAgrBAlgOwgC9cAHACgCIoAjAY0rghspkRUYgHIu4e%2BuASgBcAWABQEKRDABTAG6yoAGwD6AFwCepWeViCJ0mQqVqtOvYgOTpcxSo3bdUFNaN3Tji1HRvbJh3NnLGsJUEhYBGQXDGwEADY8QhIKanpOFjYOJn5c3h4RQ397Myc9GD8pD0CypErjEq9nVyKqgNLvX1aGzyC9EO7qjud46yA

Why wouldn't A be bound to _T2?

Because A is bound to Iterable[_T2], and _T2 is inferred from that. You don't say that zip should produce (str, A) tuples, do you?

Oh, right. I still haven't gotten used to the Python-3.12-style generics.

Removed that comment altogether, as I'm not sure what would be an accurate restatement for the point I was trying to make. Could mypy infer _T2 ~ int from the OP's type of A.__iter__, and it just doesn't, or is there a technical reason not to?

There is a reason, I commented on the OP and will answer today. You don't want something of type Iterable[Any] to be further checked on every call site.

(same problem with "new" generics TBH, they just don't look right...)
